# How to prevent database login window in crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am developing a windows application and I use Crystal Report in it (I am new to Crystal reports) the problem I am facing is when I test the report at first load it works fine but when I try to refresh the report it gives me the database login window, is there a way to prevent this window? and how to set the connection string for the report using code?

Notes: 
1-I tried

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_ReportRefresh(object source, CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ViewerEventArgs e)
    {
        Myreport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "server", "dbname", false);
    }
```

but I still get the database login window.

2-I use crystal report drag and drop to create my report.

3-this is a windows application and sql server 2008 database C# is the programming language.

4-server in the application may or may not be in the same pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The SetDatabaseLogon function wasn't working for me so I had to manually assign connection details to each table in the report. I thought the function was geared for SQL Server (I'm using Sybase ASE), but you may be having the same issue as I was.

```
ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connInfo.ServerName = "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};Server=x.x.x.x;Port=x;";
connInfo.DatabaseName = "dbname";
connInfo.UserID = "username";
connInfo.Password = "password";

TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo;

foreach(Table table in reportDoc.Database.Tables)
{
  table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
  table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connInfo.ServerName;
  table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connInfo.DatabaseName;
  table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connInfo.UserID;
  table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connInfo.Password;

  // Apply the schema name to the table's location
  table.Location = "dbo." + table.Location;
}
```

Clearly your connInfo.ServerName will differ, but I've included the pattern I used for anyone else stuck with this same problem but on ASE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much it partially worked, I mean it changed the server name and the database name in the database login window but the window still show up asking for the password, is there and solution for this?

Comment: It worked now I forgot to put it in load too that was the problem thank you so much :-D

Comment: *Happy dance* Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = selectallrecord();
        CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
        cr1.SetDataSource(dt);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;


    }



    public DataTable selectallrecord()
    {
        Connection c = new Connection();
        //c.main();

        if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            c.cn.Close();
            c.cn.Open();
        }

        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        string USER = "";
        USER = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfo";
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(USER, c.cn);
        DA.Fill(DS);
        DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0];
        return DT;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks SumitG I got it Zec answer worked fine, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are closing the connection then when you refresh it doesnt re-open the connection...can you post your full code to verify?

Comment: This is the only code I use in the form everything else is just drag and drop no code what so ever, it is a form holds a crystal report viewer and the report bound using the tasks menu for the viewer and I have no other code but the report refresh I put in the question, and your answer is logical but I don't neither open nor close the connection, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just give your data base credentials to method SetDatabaseLogon as below 
 Report.SetDatabaseLogon("", "XXX") for access db

Report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "XXXXX","ServerName", "DatabaseName") for Sql server.

but give after the line step 
Report.SetDataSource(Dt)

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables;
            SalesManVisit cryRpt = new SalesManVisit();

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = @"TLPL_ICT_OPR\xxxxxxxxx";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxxxxx";

            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "xxxxx";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "xxxxxx";



            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            cryRpt.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was by installing SQL Server 2014 Client Tool Connectivity, and backward client connectivity components using SQL Server setup source.

asp below image......... only install the Client Tool Connectivity not full Sql server database...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the "Database Fields" in "Field Explorer"  are used on the report
Remove all Tables from the DataSet that won't be used on the report
Field Explorer >> Database Fields, Right CLick >> Database Expert >> Selected Tables

Note: This pop up appears if datatable is empty